# Maven 3.3.9 version upgrade revert back to previous version once after windows restart

Tags: windows, maven

I worked with maven 3.2.5 version. There I created environment variable as "M3_HOME" & pointed to 3.2.5 installation folder & appended bin folder to "PATH" variable. I upgraded maven to 3.3.9 version. here is the only changed I have done, changed the "M3_HOME" variable point location to 3.3.9 installation folder. it has worked & I was able to work with new version until restart. I'm working on windows 10. when machine restarts it will revert back to 3.2.5 version. When I echo the "M3_HOME" in CMD it displays 3.3.9 version. but when echo "PATH" variable it shows older version. I double checked the "PATH" variable using setup UI as well. I can't notice a change. when I load environment variable setup & hit ok button & then open a CMD & check. then it works with new version until reboot the machine. this is strange. is anyone has idea on this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding folder location directly to the "PATH" variable instead of using M3_HOME variable. But still couldn't find out root cause for this strange behavior

Answer (score 2):

Check the %PATH% variable after the restart.

M3_HOME has nothing to do in terms of maven version resolution. PATH does.

PATH works in a way that you can define many places to look for, and the first matching directory that has a binary you're looking for will match.

So make sure that PATH value's first entry indeed contains the path to maven 3.3.9

Comment: There is only one value refer to maven in directory. When I echo PATH variable just after restart it displays old folder path. Then move to the environment variable set up UI & hit Ok button (without any change). & then echo PATH variable in new CMD. it shows newest folder location. problem is why this reset in every reboot. i have removed the 3.2.5 folder as well. but still refers

Comment: There can be many reasons for such a behavior. Maybe people with more experience in Windows administration will provide a more qualified answer, IMO it can be a policy (stored somewhere on the network) that just "overrides" the definitions. It can be a case if its not your "home computer", but rather a "corporate machine" that was provided with preinstalled profiles.

Comment: Alternatively it can be some sort of script that gets executed when the windows starts, again "corporate policies"

Comment: thank you mark for your help. I'll check these policies as well. I removed the "M3_HOME" variable reference in PATH variable & directly added the folder location path. now its working even after reboot. But still couldn't find out the reason